# Profiling start time for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, boot

I want to know how much time is taken by Ubuntu 14.04 when we start it. So for this I have added the below line in `rc.local`

```
awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"($1%60)}' /proc/uptime > /var/log/uptime.log
```

It is showing about 28 seconds. Can someone let me know how can I get more information about what steps are adding to this 28 seconds?

Comment: dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/744545/how-to-determine-boot-time

Comment: I am looking for the time taken in various phases of boot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bootchart package does this.

Comment: You should explain how to install and use the package.

Comment: Actually it does answer the question, just without any handholding. And no, I'm not going to write a tutorial on bootchart here. Why should I? I haven't used the package myself, and the OP can read the docs as well as I can.